# JDO shared-join-tables foreign-keys aren't valid

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

Please assume the following mapping

```
Class PieChart{
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", table = "chart_metrics_rel")
        @Join(column = "chart_fk")
        @Order(column = "order")
        @Element(dependent = "true", column = "chart_metric_fk")
        @Extensions({ @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "relation-discriminator-column", value = "chart_type"),
                @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "relation-discriminator-pk", value = "true"),
                @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "relation-discriminator-value", value = "pie") })
        private List<ChartMetric> metrics;
}
```

This works as expected but the problem is that I have the same exact mapping with another class called `TimeseriesChart` which have a whole another table with different `id`'s. So the `chart_fk` column in the mapping shown above may sometimes point to `PieChart` and some other times point to `TimeseriesChart`. So the shared join table is created with 2 foreign-keys on the `chart_fk` column, once pointing to `pie_charts` (i.e. `PieChart`, the current class) and once pointing to the `timeseries_chart` (i.e. `TimeseriesChart`).

Which is not allowing me to add elements to the join table unless the `chart_fk` value exists in **both** the pie and timeseries tables !

I checked the docs and used the `generateForeignKey` annotation attribute for `@Join` but it isn't working.

That's the attribute's description:

```
generateForeignKey  (String)    ORM:Whether to generate a FK constraint on the join table (when not specifying the name)
```

So why does the attribute has no effect as the foreign-keys are still generated ?

And what name is `when not specifying the name` referring to ? the join table's or the FK's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that vendor extension clearly applies to sharing a join table between relations to the same type (as per what the DN docs show), then you're trying to apply it where it is not intended, hence user-error.

If you have two `List<Chart>` fields and one has one subclass (PieChart), and the other a different subclass (TimeseriesChart) then it is potentially applicable there (all of our tests are based around Collections of the same element type), but you present no such information.

Comment: thank you but I'm sorry I don't understand your second paragraph. My collection will always be of one type `ChartMetric`. `PieChart` and `TimeseriesChart` are the classes, each containing such a collection of `ChartMetric` objects. I differentiate between entries (i.e. in the shared join table) for `Pie` or `Timeseries` classes by the `relation-discriminator-value` extension. And why doesn't the `generateForeignKey` attribute work as I expect ?

Comment: This extension is for class A having two collections of the same element type. As per the DN docs

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. I understand now what I've done wrong. But is there a reason why the `generateForeignKey` attribute doesn't work as I expected ?